# Checkmate with two bishops of same colour

Tags: endgame, bishops, kings

Is it possible to checkmate King with two bishops of same colour in the endgame?.

Is it possible in Chess to get this position in reality?

Position:

King with Two bishops of same colour V/S King.

Comment: The only way to get two bishops of the same color is via underpromotion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is **no possible checkmate** with 2 (or more) same-coloured bishops against a bare king. The game is drawn immediately.

Indeed, if White has light-squared bishops then:

- when the black king stand on a dark square, it cannot be attacked
- when the black king stand on a light square, it can be attacked but there are at least two adjacent dark squares (more if it isn't in a corner), of which the white king can only deny one : Black is in check but not in checkmate and the king escapes.

For example, in the position (the most White can get) White: Kc2, Bf4, Bc5 / Black Ka1 :

1.Be5 is check but a2 is not controlled: 1...Ka2 and the game is a draw.

If you add a Black pawn, a checkmate pattern become possible. However, it takes 5 bishops (!) in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvZa7sRbjho) study by Alexei Troitsky (thanks to @HaukeReddmann for the reference) for White to be able to force a checkmate !

Comment: To clarify, the game is drawn because the opposing king can always stay on the opposite color squares as the bishops, and the other king isn't enough to force anything.

Comment: @Evergalo: The study is not by Loyd, but Troitsky. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvZa7sRbjho) Just FYI. Also, please extend the answer (e.g. "a mated bK must be checked by a wB, but even in the corner it has two flights of the other color which the wK can't control") as I'm tempted to edit that in :-)